# dovecot mail storage auto detection failed

Tags: dovecot

I setup a new user called sales, and gave it a password. Although it has a home directory, i set login to /sbin/nologin.

```
dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<sales>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1,   lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=12938, secured, session=<94SotWVRoAB/AAAB>
Jun  7 21:49:24 www dovecot: pop3(sales): Error: user sales: Initialization failed: Namespace '': Mail storage autodetection failed with home=/home/sales
Jun  7 21:49:24 www dovecot: pop3(sales): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

Did i have to initialise the mailbox in the homedirectory? What did i forget. I didn't change anything to the default dovecot.conf, i just installed the package with yum install dovecot (so latest version).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well hard to say with that limited informations. On which platform (Fedora, centos, rhel, ...) do your run dovecot? What's the output in the server log as written in above. What's clear the user sales have some errors in his config. Does any other user works?

Comment: It's on aws: Linux 4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 6 18:22:38 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. I only have one user setup currently. What do you mean by server log output ?

Comment: aws have differnt rpm based images. I refer to this line `Jun  7 21:49:24 www dovecot: pop3(sales): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.` **Does any other user works?**

Comment: i think dovecot logs to maillog, so that's all i have. And as i said, sales is the only user i have currently configured (i have the ec2-user, but i don't know how to setup a password for that one. That works with local mail, but i haven't been able to test it with dovecot for the aforementioned reason).

Comment: have you take a look into the auth and messages log. please can you post the output of `cat /etc/redhat-release` `doveconf -n` . do you have set a password for the user sales?

Comment: [ec2-user@www ~]$ dovecot -n
# 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64  
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}

Comment: uh that's hard to read. please can you past it in gist or similar paste service. can you login via ssh with the user sales? does the user sales have a valid shell? Please take also a look into the doc  https://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/PAM and test the user with `doveadm user sales`

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this. I needed to uncomment the mail_location in 10-auth.conf i believe to point to the mbox (as it says in the file, because this is a new user there is no mailbox yet. After you also need to change the /var/spool/mail/user to 0600 as you will get a permission. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have `mail_location` in the 10-auth.conf file but 10-mail.conf

Comment: If you don't have `mail_location` just add it. The value may vary, for me it was
`mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n`